# On reciprocal-sums of integer polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Let's consider the class $P \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of nonconstant polynomials whose degree is at least two and with no roots in the positive integers.

For $p \in P$, I'm interested in considering sums of the form $$S_{p,N} = \sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{p(j)}$$

$$\textbf{Question 1: Size}$$

If we assume the coefficients are nonnegative (with the leading coefficient positive), it's easy to deduce an absolute upper bound of $2$, by comparing with $\sum n^{-2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. However, we allow negative coefficients, in which case it's not as clear if there is such a simple upper bound (at least not to me).

> What is $\sup\{S_{p,N}: (p,N) \in P \times \mathbb{N}\}$? Further, for a fixed degree $d \geq 2$, what is $\sup\{S_{p,N}: (p,N) \in P \times \mathbb{N} \ \text{and} \ \text{deg}(p) = d\}$?

I've tried Lagrange interpolation style arguments to prove that the former is $\infty$, but have not quite been able to make it work.

$$\textbf{Question 2: Integrality}$$

For a given $p$, at most how many $N$ exist such that $S_{p,N}$ is an integer? Since $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p(j)}$ converges and $p$ nonconstant, it's easy to see that there can only be finitely many such $N$.

Comment: Is your intuition that the sup is infinite or finite?  Infinite would be quite surprising to me.  I think the sup for the quadratic case can probably be found explicitly.

Comment: @ErickWong I was thinking along the following lines. For a given $M>0$, if the polynomial is of sufficiently higher degree (much greater than $M$, say), we could force $p(i) = 1$ for each $i \in S$, where $S \subset [N]=\{1,2,...,N\}$ with $|S| = \lfloor M \rfloor$ using a Lagrange interpolation argument. Then if we could somehow control $\sum_{i \in [N ] \setminus S} p(i)^{-1}$ in such a way that it's magnitude isn't too large compared to $M$, then $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} p(i)^{-1} \approx O(M)$

Comment: I'm not sure this works though since I believe in general Lagrange interpolation doesn't work with polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. That is, given a bunch of points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, we can't be sure a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ exists which goes through precisely those points. But it was my initial thought.

Comment: Ah I see you expect the global sup to be infinite and the degree-specific one to be finite: sure, that does makes sense, apologies for misreading your remark.

Comment: Counterexample to the strong version of Question 2: $p=(x-1)^2+2, N=3$ yields $1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6 = 1$.

Comment: Another example for $N=3$: $(x-2)^2+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer for 1: take the polynomial $p(x)=(x-1)^2(x-2)^2..(x-m)^2+1$. Then $p(k)=1, k=1,..m, p>0$ on the reals so no integer roots, no negative terms and obviously $S_{p,N} >  m$ for $N \ge m$, so definitely the supremum on all polynomials and all $N$ is infinity, while in degree $2m$ we see that the supremum is bigger than $m$

Edit later - actually we can even take $q(x)=(x-1)(x-2)..(x-m)+1$ since it is at least $1$ on the natural numbers and then we get that in degree $m$ the supremum is greater than $m$

Comment: This works, thank you.

Comment: the interesting part is to prove that the supremum in fixed degree is finite and get an estimate on it; I have no idea currently how to approach part 2

Comment: @Conrad I think I have a strategy for showing that the supremum is finite for fixed $d$.  Working on optimizing the parameters and making sure it actually goes through :).

Comment: @Erick Wong my intuition is that the upper bound in degree $d$ shouldn't be far from $d$ and definitely $O(d)$

Comment: I was able to get $4d + o(1)$ and I think it can be shaved down to $3d$ or $2d$ without too much drama, but not sure how to get down as low as $d + o(d)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that the supremum in fixed degree is finite, though my upper bound doesn’t feel particularly tight.  I found it simpler to consider the wider class of all integer polynomials of degree $\ge 2$ and the following variant sum:

$$S’_p := \sum_{\substack j\in \mathbb Z\\p(j)\ne 0} \frac1{|p(j)|}.$$

It’s easy to see by triangle inequality that $S’_p > |S_{p,N}|$, so it’s enough to show that $S’_p$ is bounded by a function of $\deg(p)$.  The extra restriction on $j$ doesn’t affect us on the domain $P$, since it can only exclude $j \le 0$.

We now consider the linear factorization of $p$ over $\mathbb C$:

$$p(x) = m(x-c_1)\cdots(x-c_d),$$

where $m$ is a non-zero integer, hence $|m| \ge 1$.  Let $a_i$ be the real part of $c_i$.  Then it is easy to see that for any real value of $x$,

$$|p(x)| \ge |m| \prod_{1\le i\le d} |x - a_i|.$$

Here is a simple but crucial observation:

> For any integer radius $r\ge 1$, there are at most $2dr$ distinct integer values of $j$ which satisfy $|j-a_i| < r$ for some $i$.

For any $j$ outside of this set, we immediately have $|p(j)| \ge r^d$.  Let’s partition the index set into:

$$J_1 := \{ j \in \mathbb Z : \min_i |j - a_i| < 2\}, \\ J_2 :=  \{ j \in \mathbb Z : 2 \le \min_i |j - a_i| < 3\}, 
\\ J_3 :=  \{ j \in \mathbb Z : 3 \le \min_i |j - a_i| < 4\}, $$

and so on.

For any $j \in J_k$ with $k \ge 2$, we have $|p(j)| \ge k^d$.  For $j\in J_1$ we can use the trivial bound $|p(j)| \ge 1$ since $p(j)$ is an integer (recall that if $p(j)=0$ it’s excluded from $S’_p$), so the bound $k^d$ is uniform.  So we get the following upper bound:

$$S’_p \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty |J_k| k^{-d}.$$

The prior observation gives us upper bounds for the partial sums of $|J_k|$.  The fact that $k^{-d}$ is decreasing in $k$, combined with partial summation (or the rearrangement inequality) shows that the RHS achieves its maximum when we first maximize $J_1$, then $J_2$ with respect to our choice of $J_1$, and so on.

This gives the case $|J_1| = 4d$ and $|J_k| = 2d$ for all other $k$, so we finally have

$$S’_p \le 2d + 2d \sum_{k\ge 1} k^{-d} = 2d(1+\zeta(d)).$$

Since $\zeta(d)-1 \sim 2^{-d}$ for large $d$, this is essentially $4d + o(1)$.  As a concrete bound we can probably take $4d + 6/d$ for all $d\ge 2$.

Comment: Actually I think your proof can be refined to give $d +o(d)$ since for the set $J_1$ and a fixed $a_k$ only one integer $q_k$ at most (and that only if the separation $|q_k-a_k|$ is very small) causes trouble while the others can be absorbed by a $2^{-d+1}$ if the $a_j$ are sufficiently separated, say by $2$ ; if some of the roots are not separated then automatically the number of troublesome integers reduces as they coincide for different roots if said roots are close